# Ssh stay up changing from ethernet to wifi

Tags: ssh

I connect to internet using ethernet cable and wifi at same time. But when i'm connected to a pc via ssh, if i unplug the ethernet cable i loose ssh connection, i expected ssh stay up and use wifi. Is it possible to achieve this? I'm using ubuntu 18.04, ip via dhcp on both connections.

Thanks

Comment: [mosh](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but you could try bonding the network interfaces in to a single bond https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding and that way, it would be a single IP address that the SSH server would be talking with. It may make the bandwidth and latency, a bit worse, but may provide the seamless connection you would like, and not just for ssh.

However, this page seems to specifically talk about what you want to do, and describes how to make it prefer the ethernet when it is available: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding